# Set a value on Expiration Date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, job-scheduling

There is a way in MySQL to set a value in a specific datetime. For example:

Today in my Table Test there is

```
Id    Value     Expiration Date
1       0      2012-08-07 18:20
2       0      2012-08-10 15:20
```

Tomorrow i'd like to have

```
Id    Value     Expiration Date
1       1      2012-08-07 18:20
2       0      2012-08-10 15:20
```

The way to do that is just with a job (some timer...)? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to achive this is by creating [EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) in MySQL as:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_name 
    SET Value = 1
    WHERE DATE(Expiration Date) < CURRENT_DATE AND
          Value = 0;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```